# Why isnt my python socket server receiving the messages?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, python-multithreading, chatroom

so i am making a chatroom in python using sockets for practice. I have made the server code using threading so that i can have more clients. Ive also made the client code, and when i try to run two clients at once so that they message from one to another, they connect to server, but the server doesnt seem to be receiving the message sent from either of the clients.
SERVER CODE:

```
import select
from threading import *


server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

# takes the first argument from command prompt as IP address
IP_address = "127.0.0.1"

# takes second argument from command prompt as port number
Port = int("50204")

server.bind((IP_address, Port))

server.listen(1000)

list_of_clients = []


def clientthread(conn, addr):
    # sends a message to the client whose user object is conn
    conn.send("Welcome to this chatroom!")

    while True:
        try:
            message = conn.recv(4096)
            if message:
                print("<" + addr[0] + "> " + message.decode("UTF-8"))

                # Calls broadcast function to send message to all
                message_to_send = "<" + addr[0] + "> " + message
                broadcast(message_to_send.encode("UTF-8"), conn)

            else:
                remove(conn)

        except:
            continue


def broadcast(message, connection):
    for clients in list_of_clients:
        if clients != connection:
            try:
                clients.send(message)
            except:
                clients.close()

                # if the link is broken, we remove the client
                remove(clients)


def remove(connection):
    if connection in list_of_clients:
        list_of_clients.remove(connection)


while True:
    conn, addr = server.accept()


    list_of_clients.append(conn)

    # prints the address of the user that just connected
    print(addr[0] + " connected")

    # creates and individual thread for every user
    # that connects
    Thread(target=clientthread, args=(conn, addr))

conn.close()
server.close()
```

CLIENT CODE:

```
import socket
import sys
import time


class client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.server_ip = "127.0.0.1"
        self.port = 50204
        self.s = self.connect()

    def connect(self):
        try:
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        except socket.error:
            print("Failed to create socket.")
            sys.exit()
        print("Socket created")

        try:
            s.connect((self.server_ip, self.port))
        except socket.error:
            print("Failed to connect to ip " + self.server_ip)

        print("Connected to: " + str(s.getsockname()))
        return s

    def SocketQuery(self, Sock, cmd):
        try:
            try:
                # Send cmd string
                Sock.send(cmd)
                print("Sent!")
                time.sleep(1)
            except socket.error:
                # Send failed
                print("Send failed!")
                sys.exit()
            reply = Sock.recv(4096)
            return reply
        except ConnectionResetError:
            print("Server is down!")

    def SocketClose(self, Sock):

        # close the socket
        Sock.close()
        time.sleep(.300)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = client()
    c.connect()
    print("connected")
    while True:
        inp = input(">>> ")
        if inp == ":q":
            break
        reply = c.SocketQuery(c.s, inp.encode("UTF-8"))
        if reply:
            print(reply.decode("UTF-8"))
    c.SocketClose(c.s)
```

So as i have already mentioned, they do connect, but dont send/receive messages.
i have checked the value in `conn.recv()`, and it is the same, also everything gets encoded to UTF-8 before sent, and then decoded back. I cant seem to find any other problem except that im running them all on localhost.
If anyone knows the answer to this, please tell me.
cheers!

Comment: How can you 'check the value in `conn.recv()`', and how can you know everything is 'decoded back', if there is no sending and receiving?

Comment: Unfortunately you neither documented what the code is intended to do nor the general design nor do you show exactly where the problem is. Moreover you simple continue in the server when `recv` fails without at least showing details of why `recv` failed. Some more obvious problems: Your client sends and then expects to receive content but your server broadcasts the message from the client to all clients but the sender - thus `recv` in the sender will hang. Also you give the wrong argument when removing a client in the server, i.e. it should be `connection` and not `clients` what you remove.